# El marco de la pantalla del emulador se desborda y tiene un tamaño exagerado

Tags: android, android-studio, emulador

[image: Emulador Android]

Estoy intentando usar el emulador de android studio pero al momento de correr el dispositivo el marco de la pantalla sale mucho más grande y no se por que

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega como definiste el AVD, más información , revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.